# is there a javascript website/wiki/reference corner where we can see which browsers support *selected-function*?

Tags: javascript, documentation, wiki, document

does anyone know of any javascript website/wiki/reference where we can see which browsers support *selected-function* ?

I mean I often go to MDC to get the api and stuff like that but usually beside the API they do not write the supported browsers.. so basically often I have to test it myself and see if say the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent)'s screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey, relatedTarget works "as expected" in the latest versions of the top 5 browsers: IE/FF/Chrome/Opera/Safari

Ok I'm not lazy but I'm just looking for a better alternative..

Comment: Have you checked quirksmode.org?

Comment: @Cracker yep its pretty cool however it doesn't have everything. specifically the stuff i've mentioned in the question: the screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey, relatedTarget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try PPK's [Quirksmode Master Compatibility Chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) for starters. The links on the left of that main chart lead off to more specific charts. The site is kept up to date, and also has lots of information about mobile browsers.

Comment: i've actually alr checked out that site. its pretty cool however it doesn't have everything. specifically the stuff i've mentioned in the question: the screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey, relatedTarget

Comment: @Pacerier yes, it actually does have [information on those things.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos) [Also here.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)  Use the "Search" box :-)

Comment: k cool, its good then (though I find it weird that the second link decides to ignore Chrome)

Comment: Well, up at the top it does say, "page last changed 3 years ago" :-)